# How do I get URL to an MVC action & maintain strong typing/intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got a project where I am using .NET MVC 4 and AngularJS.  I'd like to use MVC partial views for my Angular templates, but to do this I need the URL's to these templates.

`<div ng-include="'@Url.Action("Sidebar")'"></div>` doesn't seem to work, it just returns an empty string.  How can I get the URL returned here AND maintain strong typing/intellisense in Visual Studio.

---

With strong typing I get UI feedback and build errors when an incorrect view is passed in

[image: Valid view]
[image: Invalid view]

I've seen suggestions online of other extension methods that just take strings as the action name, which do not provide strong typing.

---

On an older project I worked on, we were using T4MVC templates and I could just call a custom extension method like: `@MVC.MyPartialView().ToUrl()`

Which worked like this:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class ActionResultHelper
    {

        public static string ToUrl(this ActionResult actionResult)
        {
            var callInfo = actionResult.GetT4MVCResult();
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
            var url = urlHelper.AbsoluteAction(callInfo.Action, callInfo.Controller, callInfo.RouteValueDictionary);
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

However I do not know how to make this work in my current project where we do not want to use T4MVC.

Comment: T4MVC was created to exactly solve this problem. I don't think there is another solution.

Comment: @Kaido: Is it possible to make an extention method like `@Html.Action("Sidebar").ToUrl()`?  Also, why doesn't `@Url.Action("Sidebar")` return a URL like it seems to imply it would?

Comment: `@Url.Action("Sidebar")` shouldn't return an empty string. Looks like you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Chris Barr @Url.Action("Sidebar") should work despite no intellisense - if  you don't mind no intellisense, then try setting the controller parameter @Url.Action("Sidebar","Home"). Also post your controller / action code as this will help us pinpoint the runtime issue